# PHP Do something on MySQL Row Added

Tags: php, mysql, push

I need a way to constantly (in a loop) check if a new MySQL row was added, and if so, do some thing with it, specifically send a notification to users that it pertains to, but I can handle that. I just need to know how to execute code when the number of MySQL rows changes.

Comment: Use crontab/sheduled tasks to launch php code in set interval, connect to DB, check a count, do stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You might wish to consider using a MySQL trigger on insert and/or delete:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be in a coding language. I need to trigger an AJAX or WebSocket (to be decided) when the row is added, not modify the MySQL database.